# How to deal ffplay being too slow playing iPhone's videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, freebsd, x264, libx264, openh264

Trying to play a 3840x2160 video recorded by an iPhone 7 (@30fps), I get frequent pauses -- in the video, music keeps playing.

This happens both in firefox and when `ffplay` is invoked to play the file directly -- from command-line. The CPU is a dual E6700  @3.20GHz -- not super fast, but it should be able to play smoothly, shouldn't it? Video is Intel's "series 4" integrated chipset -- again, not a speed-daemon, but it should be adequate... Support for Intel's VA API is included.

I build ffmpeg-4.1 from source using [FreeBSD port](http://FreshPorts.org/multimedia/ffmpeg). As you can see, the port has a maddening amount of options -- including several different ones for the 264-codec.

Any suggestions for improving the decoding speed to the point, where it is watchable by a human? Thank you!

Comment: What is the fps value shown in the progress status for `ffmpeg -i video -an -f null -`.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. Questions about software on FreeBSD should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/